# Удаленные локально директории сохранились на гитхабе

Tags: git, github

Я поработал над проектом, расположил директории более логично и удалил ненужные директории. Закоммитил изменения и залил на гитхаб. Но оказалось, что удаленные директории, которых больше нет в локальном репозитории, сохранились на гитхабе. Как удалить их оттуда?

> `$ git status`
>   On branch master
>   Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
>   Changes not staged for commit:
>   (use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)
>   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
>   deleted: components/tick/tick.js
>   Untracked files:
>   (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
>   .gitignore
>   no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: Проверьте, не находятся, ли, случайно, те дирректории в .gitignore?

Comment: @test123, нет, не находятся.

Comment: Ещё одно уточнение. Удалённые директории остались в одном из коммитов старых версий? Или же в актуальном коммите, в котором вы сейчас находитесь?

Comment: @test123,  я получил такое сообщение: On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

 deleted:    components/tick/tick.js

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 .gitignore

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: *deleted: components/tick/tick.js* — надо удалить файл не только из файловой системы (точнее, из неё и не надо было удалять, git с этим справится самостоятельно), но и из хранилища: `git rm путь/имя-файла`. а потом закоммитить и отправить на github.